# Filter for file extensions using os.walk but with restrictions on file name

Tags: python

I am using [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) to iterate through a directory and want to count the number of lines I have in .java files of that directory. I've found from other answers that I can use [fnmatch.filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) to only get .java files like this:

```
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(project_directory):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.java'):
            # get line count
```

However, I want to exclude a few files that have a specific name, say MyExclusion.java. How can I enhance the filter the avoid searching these files? The best I can figure out is to add another conditional:

```
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(project_directory):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.java'):
            if file != 'MyExclusion.java':
                # get line count
```

Can fnmatch.filter be used to do this, or am I forced to add a conditional check here?

Comment: No... Its similar to Unix style regex matching only

Comment: @thefourtheye If I managed to piece together a regex pattern to ignore that keyword do you think it would work? I'd have to play around with regex to get the right pattern though.

Comment: If the number of files to exclude is not much, I would recommend keeping them in a set and checking if the current file is in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have passed the filter to another filter function or simply construct a list-comprehension.

```
>>> files = ['manifest.xml', 'Test.java', 'Foo.java', 'MyExclusion.java']
>>> [f for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.java')
...     if f not in ('MyExclusion.java', 'Bad.java')]
['Test.java', 'Foo.java']
```

Alternative method using regex: compile a pattern and replace that into the if condition

```
>>> import re
>>> patt = re.compile('^(MyExclusion|Bad)')
>>> [i for i in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.java') if not patt.search(i)]
['Test.java', 'Foo.java']
```

Consider using generator expression instead of a list comprehension, so that you would do something like:

```
    for file in (i for i in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.java') if not patt.search(i)):
        # get line count
```

To eliminate generating the second list all in one go to potentially reduce memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks! I used the pattern method and it worked great.